# Python: Split dictionary inside a list into multiple lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split

I would like to split a string like this:

```
my_list = [{'lat': -27.239722222222223, 'name': 'Geraldton', 'long': 114.62222222222222}]
```

into individual values:

```
my_list2 = ['lat', -27.239,'name', 'Geraldton', 'long', 114.6222]
```

or into dictionary or list where I can call the elements to use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I have tried everything, been stuck for hours...

Comment: **I have tried everything**, we would like to see some of them

Comment: most successful attempt:

Comment: def main():

    my_list = [{'lat': -27.239722222222223, 'name': 'Geraldton', 'long': 114.62222222222222}]
    my_list1 = []
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        my_list1.append(list(my_list[i]))

    print my_list1

main()

Comment: Has their account been deleted?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to get all tuples `(key, value)` in the dictionary, all that is left is to flatten them:

```
my_list = [{'lat': -27.239722222222223, 'name': 'Geraldton', 'long': 114.62222222222222}]
dictionary = my_list[0]
# flatten using list comprehension
flattened = [item for tup in dictionary.items() for item in tup]
```

Output:

```
['lat', -27.239722222222223, 'long', 114.62222222222222, 'name', 'Geraldton']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
list1 = [{'lat': -27.239722222222223, 'name': 'Geraldton', 'long': 114.62222222222222}]
list2 = []
for key in list1[0]:
    list2.append(key)
    list2.append(list1[0][key])
```